# MVC 4 Razor Engine Getting data from textbox and sending another textbox by clicking button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to explain my question by giving an example. For example , I have 3 input places

```
<input id="txtA" type="text" class="search-text" />
<input id="txtB" type="text" class="search-text" />
<input id="txtC" type="text" class="search-text" />
```

and I have submit button

```
<input id="hesapla" type="submit" value="Hesap" name="but" />
```

and one more text area to show the result

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" class="search-text" />
```

Lets come to my question - User will enter numbers to these input areas and when user click the button there will be calculations between the numbers entered -for example summation- and the result will be shown in the latest text area. It is very simple I think but I have just started mvc and I couldnt get what I meant from the documents I read and watched. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to do the calculations via JavaScript, or do you want the results posted back to the server so you can do the calculations there?

Comment: sorry I forgot to indicate that. I dont want to do it with javascript I want to do it on server side.

Comment: Are you coming from a web forms background?

Comment: yes. in this there is no txtA.text I think right?

Comment: So the MVC paradigm is very different than web forms in this respect.  This example would of course be very easy in web forms, attach a button event handler to your submit button that sets Text1.Text.  MVC doesn't have button event handlers, instead you have only HTTP events (get, post, etc).  So your input button will cause a Post event.  You create an overload in your Controller to capture that Post event and then create a new Model to pass to a View (either the same View or a new one (ie SearchResultsView)).  Then you do inline data-binding in the View using Razor syntax.

Comment: thank you very much again I have to study on this more :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#hesapla").click(function () {
                var t1 = $("#txtA");
                var t2 = $("#txtB");
                var t3 = $("#txtC");
                var Result = 0;
                var aa = parseFloat(t1.val());
                var bb = parseFloat(t2.val())
                var cc = parseFloat(t3.val())
                Result = aa + bb + cc ;
                $("#Text1").val(Result);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

change button type :

```
<input id="hesapla" type="button" value="Hesap" name="but" />
```

Please try this DEMO : insert all three textbox values and see what happens

```
http://jsfiddle.net/E89P6/
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you on your way:

This assumes you have a SearchController in the Controller folder, a Search.cshtml in the View folder and the url is localhost/Search

```
public class SearchController
{
   ///GET
   public ActionResult Index(){
       return View();
   }

   ///POST
   public ActionResult Index(string txtA, string txtB, string txtC)
   {
       //perform calculation and assign to string result
       string result = "Search Results!";
       return View (result);
   }
}
```

View

```
@model string

@* Skipped Input Fields *@
<input id="txtResults" type="text" Value="@Model ?? String.Empty" />
```

Note:  This will not repopulate the txtA, txtB, txtC fields.  If you want to repopulate those, you'll need to create a proper `Model` class (instead of using string) and pass it to the view via the Controller `Index(string txtA, string txtB, string txtC)` method.

Answer (score 0):

I see three choices for you with your task:

**1. Pass the data to server with submited form**

For this you need assign names to your inputs, wrap them and submit button with `<form>` tag and create asp.net mvc action for recieving your values and sending back a result;

***EXAMPLE:***

*ViewModel*

```
public class CalcModelViewModel
{
    public CalcModelViewModel() : this(0) { }
    public CalcModelViewModel(int countOfInputs) 
    {
        Inputs = Enumerable.Repeat(0m, countOfInputs);
    }
    public IEnumerable<decimal> Inputs { get; set; }
    public decimal Result { get; set; }
}
```

*In controller*

```
public ActionResult Sum()
{
    return View(new CalcModelViewModel(3));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Sum(decimal[] numbers)
{
    return View(new CalcModelViewModel() { Inputs = numbers, Result = numbers.Sum() });
}
```

*View*

```
@model Mvc4Application.Controllers.CalcModelViewModel
<form id="sumForm" action="@Url.Action("Sum")" method="POST">
    @foreach (var num in Model.Inputs)
    {
        <input type="text" class="search-text" name="numbers" value="@num" />
    }

    <input id="hesapla" type="submit" value="Hesap" name="but" />
</form>

<input id="Text1" type="text" class="search-text" value="@Model.Result" />
```

**2. Pass the data to server with ajax request**

For this you could wrap your inputs with `<form>` tag for convenience (it's not neccessary), and send it to server.

***EXAMPLE***
All stays the same like in the first example, only change
the post action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Sum(decimal[] numbers)
{
    return Json(new { result = numbers.Sum() });
}
```

and add the script that send data to the server:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#hesapla").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var callback = function(response) {
                $("#Text1").val(response.result);
            }
            $.post("@Url.Action("Sum")", $("#sumForm").serialize(), callback, 'json');
        });
    })
</script>
```

**3. Calculate or sum in javascript**

Do not send any data to server and do calculations on client side. But be cautious with that because javascript sometimes could be tricky with math on float numbers.
Enter to console `0.2 + 0.1` and you will see what I mean.

***EXAMPLE***

```
$(function() {
    $("#hesapla").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sum = 0;
        $('input[name=numbers]').each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
        });
        $("#Text1").val(sum);
    });
})
```

Comment: @Amit Yes, thanks, I wrote a wrong statement about javascript. Just corrected it.